# Bound for the k-th derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, exponential-function, upper-lower-bounds

Consider $f(t)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i e^{ta_i}\right)^A$, where $a_i\in R_+$, $0\leq b_i\leq 1, \sum_i b_i=1$, $t$ - parameter, for $i=1, \ldots, n$ and $A \in R_+$.

I would like to bound from above the k-th derivative of $f$ at $t=0$, as follows:
$$
f^{(k)}\leq C(A,k)\|a\|_1.
$$
So far, I have been able to get bound on the r.h.s with $C(A, k)=A^k$, but I need a tighter bound than that.

Comment: @Eric Towers: Thank you, I have clarified the question

Comment: I don't think you can do much better than $A^k$. Consider the case where $n=1$ and $b_1=1$. In this case, $f(t)=e^{t a_1 A}$ and hence $f^{(k)}(0)=(a_1 A)^k$.

Comment: @PhoenemueX: The problem here is when I am differentiating k times, I have to  get the $\|a\|_1$ by spitting $b_i$ and $a_i$, where I am loosing a lot. I would expect bound be something like $(A/k)^k$